# Trying to add data in unsupported state at Cipher.update

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

Below code is working

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc','abcdefghijklmnop')
var http = require('http')

var userStr = 'a134aad';
var crypted = cipher.update(userStr, 'utf8', 'hex');
crypted += cipher.final('hex');
console.log(crypted);
```

But when put into a server callback it doesn't work, and throws below err when a request arriving, and node is crush:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    var userStr = 'a134aad';
    var crypted = cipher.update(userStr, 'utf8', 'hex');
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    console.log(crypted);

    res.end('hello');
}).listen(9888)

---------------------------------

7364aee753f0568f7e5171add6868b75
crypto.js:170
  var ret = this._handle.update(data, inputEncoding);
                         ^
Error: Trying to add data in unsupported state
    at Cipher.update (crypto.js:170:26)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\58\Desktop\sha256.js:12:26)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:602:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:117:23)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Check this out**

Thats mainly because every time we run the encrypt or decrypt we should repeat `crypto.createCipher('aes192', secrateKey);` and `crypto.createDecipher('aes192', secrateKey);`

```
let secrateKey = "secrateKey";
const crypto = require('crypto');


function encrypt(text) {
    const encryptalgo = crypto.createCipher('aes192', secrateKey);
    let encrypted = encryptalgo.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex');
    encrypted += encryptalgo.final('hex');
    return encrypted;
}

function decrypt(encrypted) {
    const decryptalgo = crypto.createDecipher('aes192', secrateKey);
    let decrypted = decryptalgo.update(encrypted, 'hex', 'utf8');
    decrypted += decryptalgo.final('utf8');
    return decrypted;
}

let encryptedText = encrypt("hello");
console.log(encryptedText);

let decryptedText = decrypt(encryptedText);
console.log(decryptedText);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although this is a good example, the function `createCipher` is now deprecated in favour of `createCipheriv`. A nice example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60370205/25868

Answer (score 17):

Turns out

`var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc','abcdefghijklmnop')`

should not be reused. I put it into the server callback too and the problem is solved.

Comment: I would add that the error is throws due the `final()` call https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_final_outputencoding This answer should be accepted

Answer (score 0):

You need to create cipher before using it. like:

```
let cipher = crypto.createCipher("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
```

`key` = can be any random string. (i prefer to use 32-bit long because you might get an error for not exact 32-bit long key)

`iv` = initialization vector.

both key and iv need to in utf-8.

checkout documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options

so, the final code looks like this:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
var userStr = 'a134aad';
let key = "123456781234567812345678";
let iv= crypto.randomBytes(16);
let cipher = crypto.createCipher("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
var crypted = cipher.update(userStr, 'utf8', 'hex');
crypted += cipher.final('hex');
console.log(crypted);

res.end('hello');
}).listen(9888)
```

**Also, if you find any mistakes, feel free to correct me!