# How do I replace deprecated crypto.createCipher in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, encryption

I am using following functions to encrypt/decrypt strings in Node.js:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');
var algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';
function encrypt(text) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
    try {
        var crypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex');
        crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    } catch (e) {
        return;
    }
    return crypted;
}

function decrypt(text) {
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password);
    try {
        var dec = decipher.update(text, 'hex', 'utf8');
        dec += decipher.final('utf8');
    } catch (e) {
        return;
    }
    return dec;
}
```

(password is stored separately from encoded text). New version of nodejs/crypt package complains:

```
(node:5212) [DEP0106] DeprecationWarning: crypto.createDecipher is deprecated.
```

How do I rewrite this to upgrade my source code?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**So lets say it like:**

Replace deprecated `crypto.createDecipher` usage with `crypto.createDecipheriv`

**why? because:**

according to the [deprecation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/933d8eb689bb4bc412e71c0069bf9b7b24de4f9d/doc/api/deprecations.md#dep0106-cryptocreatecipher-and-cryptocreatedecipher) docs it was due to security concerns.

Using `crypto.createCipher()` and `crypto.createDecipher()` **should be avoided as they use a weak key derivation function (MD5 with no salt) and static initialization vectors**. It is recommended to derive a key using `crypto.pbkdf2()` or `crypto.scrypt()` and to use `crypto.createCipheriv()` and `crypto.createDecipheriv()` to obtain the Cipher and Decipher objects respectively.

Link to the above reference: [Click Here](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/185#issuecomment-439208656)

**Someone also said:**

As per [crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password_options](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password_options), one now need to switch to `crypto.createDecipheriv`.

**Sample Code:**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';
const ENCRYPTION_KEY = 'Put_Your_Password_Here'; // or generate sample key Buffer.from('FoCKvdLslUuB4y3EZlKate7XGottHski1LmyqJHvUhs=', 'base64');
const IV_LENGTH = 16;

function encrypt(text) {
    let iv = crypto.randomBytes(IV_LENGTH);
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY, 'hex'), iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text);
    encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
    return iv.toString('hex') + ':' + encrypted.toString('hex');
}

function decrypt(text) {
    let textParts = text.split(':');
    let iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift(), 'hex');
    let encryptedText = Buffer.from(textParts.join(':'), 'hex');
    let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY, 'hex'), iv);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);
    decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
    return decrypted.toString();
}
```

For complete running example clone [node-cheat](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/stackoverflow_answers/crypto-create-cipheriv.js#L2) and run `node crypto-create-cipheriv.js`.

Comment: alright, see the updated answer now it has both code and node-cheat link. @StepanYakovenko

Comment: It will fire error (node:28641) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid key length

Comment: @Codebrekers that means you're not providing the correct ENCRYPTION_KEY. Please read this line carefully to make it work: https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/stackoverflow_answers/crypto-create-cipheriv.js#L9

Comment: @Codebrekers The problem is that the key needs to be 32 bytes long. To achieve this (pad or shrink to 32 bytes regardless of the size of ENCRYPTION_KEY) you can use `Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY), Buffer.alloc(32)], 32)` as second argument to `createCipheriv()` and `createDecipheriv()`

Comment: You can use `scrypt(secret, salt, 24, (err, key) => { // cipher/decipher here }) ` to ensure you have a key that is of the correct length for your algorithm. E.g. aes192 = 24 bytes (192 bits). You should use a unique salt if possible.

Comment: It is secure to store the IV with the encrypted value?

Answer (score 4):

createDecipheriv is now Deprecated. Stability: 0 - Deprecated: Use crypto.createCipheriv() instead. One can easily replace it with createCipheriv

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const ENC= 'bf3c199c2470cb477d907b1e0917c17b';
const IV = "5183666c72eec9e4";
const ALGO = "aes-256-cbc"

const encrypt = ((text) => 
{
   let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGO, ENC, IV);
   let encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64');
   encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
   return encrypted;
});

const decrypt = ((text) => 
{
   let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGO, ENC, IV);
   let decrypted = decipher.update(text, 'base64', 'utf8');
   return (decrypted + decipher.final('utf8'));
});

const encrypted_key = encrypt("HelloWorld");
const decrypted_key = decrypt(encrypted_key);
```

Comment: Your code uses cbc, but I need ctr.

Comment: Have you checked replacing the algorithm with const ALGO = "aes-256-ctr".
For me it is working for both ctr and cbc

Answer (score 0):

You can use also `createCipheriv`:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
var encryptionDecryption = {};

encryptionDecryption.Encryption = async (data, key) => {
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'base64');
  encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
  return {
    iv: iv.toString('base64'),
    encryptedData: encrypted
  };
}

encryptionDecryption.Decryption = async (encryptedData, key, iv) => {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), Buffer.from(iv, 'base64'));
  let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedData, 'base64', 'utf8');
  decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
  return decrypted;
}

module.exports = encryptionDecryption;

// driver code
// calling this function MENU use this function in API if you call here then //it says cyclic dependencies

const encrypted = encrypt(data, key);
console.log('Encrypted:', encrypted);

const decrypted = decrypt(encrypted.encryptedData, key, encrypted.iv);
console.log('Decrypted:', decrypted);
```

for execute this make this as a function in any node/javascript compiler

[image: Output]