# How to port encrypt (AES192) method from nodejs to java correctly?

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, aes

I'm trying to port this nodejs code to java

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

const encrypt = (data, key) => {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes192', key)

    let crypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'hex')
    crypted += cipher.final('hex')

    return crypted;
}
```

I've tried to use this solution:

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Hex;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public String encrypt(String data, String key) {
    try {
        var cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES"));

        var cipherText = cipher.update(data.getBytes());
        cipherText = ArrayUtils.addAll(cipherText, cipher.doFinal());

        return new String(Hex.encode(cipherText));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Cons:

1. `encrypt` method for Java returns a different value than the method for nodejs (for the same data and key).
2. In nodejs, I can put a short key (5 characters long), at the same time in java I'm catching an exception e.g. "java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 5 bytes"

Could you suggest the right solution or point on a mistake in the existing one? Thank you in advance!

Note: I'm unable to change encrypt/decrypt method in nodejs, so I need to port this to java correctly.

Comment: `createCipher()` is deprecated. The ciphertexts differ, since `createCipher()` uses an (insecure) password based key derivation function to derive the key from the password (i.e. `key` is interpreted as password).  Apply `createCipheriv()` which expects a key (if needed in combination with a reliable key derivation like PBKDF2). Otherwise you have to implement the (insecure) key derivation in Java (there are several implementations for Java available on the Web, e.g. [here](https://olabini.se/blog/tag/evp_bytestokey/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `encrypt` java version doesn't use the same logic as the javascript version.

The `encrypt` javascript function takes a **password** (the argument name `key` is misleading) and then passes it to `createCipher`. `createCipher` doesn't use the password directly, but derives a key from it. It's the derived key that is used to encrypt the message. [From NodeJs documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options) :

```
The password is used to derive the cipher key and initialization vector (IV). The value must be either a 'latin1' encoded string, a Buffer, a TypedArray, or a DataView.
```

The `encrypt` java function, on the other hand, expects a ready to use key, so you have to do the key derivation from the password yourself.

AES keys have a fixed size. [They can only be 128, 192 or 256 bits long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). (in bytes 8, 16, 32 bytes long). If you use a key with a different size, you'll get the exception `InvalidKeyException`. NodeJS didn't complain about an "invalid key length" because in actuality you were using a password, not a key. NodeJS derives a key from the password before encrypting the data.

(as mentioned in the docs) NodeJs uses OpenSSL to encrypt the data and derives the key using a function specific to OpenSSL : `EVP_BytesToKey`.

Luckily this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11786924/1789281) has an implementation of `EVP_BytesToKey` in Java. (The code is originally from [this blog entry](https://olabini.se/blog/2006/10/openssl-in-jruby/))

I adapted your code to use it. I added the final result to the end of the answer. I rarely write security code, and in this case I just adapted an existing solution, so you should review the code (or have someone else review it if you have a security team in your company) if you decide to use it.

One final comment : `createCipher` is deprecated. But you said in your question that you can't change the implementation of the javascript `encrypt` version. (If you're not the maintainer of `encrypt`) You should discuss the deprecation issue with the maintainer to understand their reasons for still using `createCipher` (which uses EVP_BytesToKey). `EVP_BytesToKey` is considered a [weak key derivation function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60370205/1789281) and OpenSSL [recommends using more modern functions for newer applications](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html#NOTES).

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Hex;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Result : " + encrypt("my secret message","pass"));
    }

    public static byte[][] EVP_BytesToKey(int key_len, int iv_len, MessageDigest md, byte[] salt, byte[] data, int count) {
        byte[][] both = new byte[2][];
        byte[] key = new byte[key_len];
        int key_ix = 0;
        byte[]  iv = new byte[iv_len];
        int iv_ix = 0;
        both[0] = key;
        both[1] = iv;
        byte[] md_buf = null;
        int nkey = key_len;
        int niv = iv_len;
        int i = 0;
        if(data == null) {
            return both;
        }
        int addmd = 0;
        for(;;) {
            md.reset();
            if(addmd++ > 0) {
                md.update(md_buf);
            }
            md.update(data);
            if(null != salt) {
                md.update(salt,0,8);
            }
            md_buf = md.digest();
            for(i=1;i<count;i++) {
                md.reset();
                md.update(md_buf);
                md_buf = md.digest();
            }
            i=0;
            if(nkey > 0) {
                for(;;) {
                    if(nkey == 0) break;
                    if(i == md_buf.length) break;
                    key[key_ix++] = md_buf[i];
                    nkey--;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if(niv > 0 && i != md_buf.length) {
                for(;;) {
                    if(niv == 0) break;
                    if(i == md_buf.length) break;
                    iv[iv_ix++] = md_buf[i];
                    niv--;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if(nkey == 0 && niv == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<md_buf.length;i++) {
            md_buf[i] = 0;
        }
        return both;
    }

    public static String encrypt(String data, String password) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            var cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            var keySizeBits = 192 / Byte.SIZE; //AES with 192 bits key = 16 bytes
            var ivSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
            final byte[][] keyAndIV = EVP_BytesToKey(keySizeBits, ivSize, md5, null, password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII), 1);
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyAndIV[0], "AES");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(keyAndIV[1]);

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

            var cipherText = cipher.update(data.getBytes());
            cipherText = ArrayUtils.addAll(cipherText, cipher.doFinal());

            return new String(Hex.encode(cipherText));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```